A lengthy integral
Help!
Here’s my code:
int_1 ^2 (\vec{\nabla}_\vec{r}L\cdot\delta\vec{r} + \vec{\nabla}_\Dot{\vec{r}}L\cdot\delta\Dot{\vec{r}}) dt

I want it to show this:

Instead, it gives me this:

How do I rectify this conundrum?
Edit: Corrected all \Vec to \vec. The problem remains.
Code prints just fine. The problem is that I can’t get the Lagrangian out of the subscript.

Neveer post only sniplets, please post a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. For example where is \Vec defined? And _\Ved{r} is always playing with fire. Does your code even compile without errors? (standard question when people tag with overleaf as so many overleaf users ignores compilation errors).

@daleif Well, I don’t know what to say to you cuz that’s what my professor wrote.

You tell your professor that they are doing their students a very large disservice by promoting a syntax that sometimes work, and other times not. But the most important thing is, as egreg mentions in his answer, NEVER ignore compilation errors just because you get a PDF out.

If I run your code (with \int) adorned with the necessary bits,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_1 ^2 (\Vec{\nabla}_\Vec{r}L\cdot\delta\Vec{r} + \Vec{\nabla}_\Dot{\Vec{r}}L\cdot\delta\Dot{\Vec{r}}) dt
\]

\end{document}

I get the following chain of errors:
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \gdef
l.7 \int_1 ^2 (\Vec{\nabla}_\Vec{r}
                                   L\cdot\delta\Vec{r} + \Vec{\nabla}_\Dot{\...

?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \gdef
l.7 ...t\delta\Vec{r} + \Vec{\nabla}_\Dot{\Vec{r}}
                                                  L\cdot\delta\Dot{\Vec{r}}) dt

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.8 \]

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.8 \]

?

and the output is

But the problem is not in the output: it's in the input! Never ignore errors.
The main problem is _\Vec{r}: the _ subscript marker isn't a magic wand that reads your mind. Always brace subscripts and superscripts, particularly as a beginner; maybe later experience will tell you when braces can safely be omitted.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{1}^{2} (
  \vec{\nabla}_{\vec{r}}L \cdot \delta\vec{r} +
  \vec{\nabla}_{\dot{\vec{r}}}L \cdot \delta\dot{\vec{r}} \,
) \, dt
\]

\end{document}

Note also \, in two places: the last vector appears too near to the closing parentheses and it's better to add a thin space in order to avoid clash; the second one is in front of the differential, which is a common typographic method for this case.
You use \Vec and \Dot, but they're exactly the same as \vec and \dot.

With the following code you get perhaps clearer output as on the board:
\[
\int_{1}^{2} \bigl[
  (\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{r}}L) \cdot \delta\vec{r} +
  (\vec{\nabla}_{\dot{\vec{r}}}L) \cdot \delta\dot{\vec{r}} \,
\bigr] \, dt
\]



@egeg Thanks so much! Your analysis was very helpful!
